# VBA compile Error: unexpected error 35010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to compile a big project in Excel however the unexpected error is showing up often but not always. One engineer told me that it is related to virtual memory. Can anyone please tell what should I do to eliminate this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code or at least the code in the area where it highlights when the error occurs? What have you tried already?

Comment: You have not mentioned any concrete details about the error, when it occurred, what code you followed. How do you expect SO community to help you without full information.

Comment: Sorry. The code shall not be posted due to non-disclosure agreement. The problem description is clear enough that the error is 35010. The problem has been solved by adding vertual memories and restart the computer.

Comment: These down votes are unfair, the code turns out to be irrelevant to the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this happened unexpectedly, the project was not particularly large. Closing the VBA host and reopening allowed the project to compile.

To fix this I'd suggest trying the simplest fixes before heading over to Advanced System Settings...

- close reopen
- repair document / worksheet
- test on other user profile
- test on other PC
- *other stuff*
- change system settings

Answer (score 1):

In control panel, go to system > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Performance settings > advance > change Virtual memory. Then select custom size and increase it to a reasonable amount of value. Initial size 8000, Maximum Size 15000. Click ok and restart the computer to make the change. And the problem goes away.

The explanation is that when VBA is compiling, the virtual memory gets filled up quickly when you are compiling a big project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the workbook was corrupted. [Repairing it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The bug appears to have been finally resolved thanks to Jamie Garroch, as documented [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-vba-compile-and-crashing-problems/dd599a63-28ba-4f7b-a6d7-98718cefa3bf?page=1).
Look for his messages dated "December 15, 2023" and "January 12, 2024".

TLDR: The presence of "AddressOf" in 64-bit VBE code is the root cause, at compile time, even if you don't execute it.

Jamie Garroch:
"I reported this issue to Microsoft in November 2022 and my team at BrightCarbon has been working with the Microsoft VBA team ever since. It looks like a fix has finally been introduced in the 64-bit version of VBE7.DLL as of Version 2402 Build 16.0.17304.20000 (I'm on the beta channel). To check if you have the fix, open this folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1
Right click the VBE7.DLL file and check the version in the Details tab as follows:
7.1.11.31 = 35010 issue
7.1.11.33 = 35010 fixed"

---

If you can't update, just comment out the code or put it under conditionals:

```
#If Win64 ' Running in Office 64-bit
    ' Don't do anything!
#Else
    ' Do your WinAPI stuff with AddressOf callbacks
#End If
```

---

Please don't forget to vote for his answer(s) on the linked page, if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it sometimes helps to recompile the VBA code (if there is one):

1. ALT+F11 to open the VBA-Editor.
2. Choose menu: Debug > Compile to recompile forms and code.
3. Reopen file.